# Export JSON value in table from Bigquery with correct quotes

Tags: json, csv, google-bigquery, double-quotes

I want to export a value of a column in Bigquery to look like:

```
| NAME    | JSON          |
| abc     | {"test": 1}   |
```

However, when I want to export this to a gzipped csv/tsv via a python code to google cloud storage with field delimiter = '\t' (https://google-cloud.readthedocs.io/en/latest/bigquery/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client.extract_table.html) , I always get something like:

```
| NAME    | JSON            | 
| abc     | "{""test"": 1}" |
```

I know about escaping, and I have been trying a lot of possibilities with escaping (using "" to escape the " or adding -values), but I can't seem to get the export as:

```
{"test": 1}
```

Please help me?

Comment: How are you exporting? What does the data in the table look like?

Comment: I edited the description, does that make things more clear?

Comment: What is reading the resulting CSV ? Depending on it, these additional quotes might be OK. For example if you read it with python pandas (newer versions), you will get a json, stored as a string : `'{"test": 1}'`. If you're reading it with something that keeps it as shown in your post, you might have to treat the file: replace "" with ", and remove the outermost double quotes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tool output is correct, but you'd need to read [RFC 4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180), the standard for CSV files, to see why.

Basically, the [JSON spec](https://json.org) says `test` needs to have double quotes, i.e. `"test"`.

Double quotes around the entire field are allowed in CSV. But the CSV spec also says that in a CSV with quoted fields, an inner quote is duplicated. This is rule 7 on section 2 of RFC 4180:

> 7. If double-quotes are used to enclose fields, then a double-quote
>    appearing inside a field must be escaped by preceding it with
>    another double quote.  For example:
>
>    "aaa","b""bb","ccc"

So whats the solution?

Possibly, you need a RFC 4180 compliant CSV reader, so you aren't writing the parsing code yourself where the file is used.

You could replace the doubled double quotes with single double quotes, and the quotes at the braces with nothing like this:

`sed -e 's/"{/{/g; s/}"/}/g; s/""/"/g;' in.csv > out.csv`

transforming

`"{""test"": 1}"`

to

`{ "test": 1}`

or using `String.replace` in JavaScript, but then the resulting csv file is NOT RFC 4180 compliant.

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation. Probably it is then not due to the export from Bigquery, but the import in Snowflake (where we push the data to). Any idea which I should adjust:
https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table.html 
Where it can be found under 'formatTypeOptions'. There are a lot of possibilities.

Comment: Found it! Thanks!

Comment: I needed to add the FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY in snowflake.